# How to enable auto refresh functionality for Power BI designer file?

Tags: powerbi

How to enable auto refresh functionality for Power BI designer file?

I have gone through this [link](https://support.powerbi.com/knowledgebase/articles/474669-refresh-data) and as per the link auto refresh functionality is not available for Power BI designer file.

Do we have any other way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Edit:refresh functionality for Power BI Designer files is now available in the service. Just schedule refresh as you would for other sources. Weave also added a 'personal gateway' if you're trying to refresh from on premises sources.

Appreciate your using Power BI,
-Lukasz

- http://dev.powerbi.com
- http://blogs.msdn.com/powerbidev
- Make a feature request: https://support.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi
- Sign up for Power BI: http://www.powerbi.com

Comment: Thanks for the links. Few questions on this. 
1) We tried to use SQL Azure as DataModel (using power query only) but I still can't see Auto refresh option enabled for it. It's saying not supported.
2) We tried Azure table as DataModel (using power query only) then it works.

Why it did not work for SQL Azure?

Comment: Yes the UI for Azure SQL in the service is not very clear.  When you use the Azure SQL connection in the www.powerbi.com UI, you're making a direct query connection to the data.  There's no refresh schedule, because the data is up to date - reports run queries live and dashboard tiles are updated every 15 minutes.

Comment: That's not happening. We have to click on Refresh Now then data are getting refreshed on tile.

Comment: Please let us know if we are missing any configuration. If above things are happening then we will be very happy. User will be able to see live data.

Comment: To use Azure SQL direct query, you'd go to the service, click get data, click 'big data and more', select Azure SQL, and then connect. After you configure that, you'll have a dataset in your PowerBI account that does direct query over your data source. You can the build your  report using the web ui. When you pin visuals to a dashboard from a report crated the way I describe, you'll get the 15 minute dashboard refresh and immediate (live queries) when you open that report or explore in that dataset.